# ZEND modular application 

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-modules

Can anybody provide me the ZEND modular running example.All working as   i m really tired trying things.

Regards
Jos

Comment: *(related)* http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=zend+module+framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a little big, but Magento is based on the Zend Framework and is very modular. The Zend classes in there are slowly being replaced by Magento-specific ones, but they still hold on to a lot of Zend Framework stuff like controllers, helpers, models.

They offer configuration for each module to hook into the router system, the admin, the templates (you may not even have to edit the template file). You can also override models, controllers, and other from the modules using the module config.

To be honest, I haven't looked that much, but when it comes to extendability: Magento is tough to beat. To use it as a base for some other system, there'd need to be improvements in other areas like Performance, Scalability, Bugs, Complexity, and Compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

[create modular application with zend](http://www.amazium.com/blog/create-modular-application-with-zend) by Jeroen Keppens.

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to go to the web site of the excellent book "[Zend Framework 1.8 Application Development](https://www.packtpub.com/zend-framework-1-8-web-application-development/book)" and download the source code of the book(which is freely available). The application completed in chapter 12 is modular and features many of the capabilities of the framework as well many great development practices so I could only assume that getting acquainted with such an app will be beneficial for you.

Comment: Hi Batsov,

Thanks for quick reply , i'll definitely see to it and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

What about [Zend Framework in Action](http://www.zendframeworkinaction.com/) by Rob Allen? It's a great book and Rob has a really easy going style and explains the multitude of topics in a very straight forward manner.

Alternatively, clone a copy of my [Zend Framework development project](https://github.com/settermjd/Zend-Framework-Development-Project) from github. I am writing it, specifically to cover all of the various concepts that are available in Zend Framework; it's using modules.

All the best,

Matt